# Econnreset error on insering larger files into db - mysql

Tags: mysql

I am submiting cart with products info and long json of different images which are data64. Everything works normally with 1-2 products, but if I add more products I get this error:
Error: read ECONNRESET

I tried sizing up the limit of json on server, but it's the same, it seems that the problem occurs in mysql.
I read that there is a limit of how many characters I can put into table but I cannot have a hardcoded value which will be provided in query (the column where images go is type JSON) for images for the products, user's choose alone, they can pick howmany they want.

Server is currently running on localhost.

Note that I didnt leave server idle which can cause this error.

Any thought would be appreciated, Thanks.